# Subsets of a multiset

Tags: combinatorics, subset

The function `Subsets[]` returns the subsets of a finite set of elements. This function has a shortcoming in that it treats repeated elements distinctively. Is there a function that returns the subset of a finite multiset of elements? That is, that unlike `Subsets[]` it treats repeated elements in-distinctively.

For example, if the new function is called `NewSubsets`, then the output should be:

```
NewSubsets[{a, b, c, c}]
```

> {{}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {c, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, 
>     c}, {b, c, c}, {a, b, c, c}}

Comment: Is the  expected output of `newFn[{a,c,b,c}]` {{}, {a}, {b}, {c, c}, {a, b}, {a, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {a, b, c, c}}, or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I would suggest 1. exploring the second argument to `Subsets` and probably 2. looking at [*`Tuples`*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html)

Comment: @tomd `Subset[{a,b,c,c,}]`outputs `{{}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {c}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {b, c}, {c, 
  c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {a, b, c, c}}`. In contrast `newSubsets[{a,b,c,c}]` outputs `{{},{a},{b},{c},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c},{c,c},...,{a,b,c,c}}`

Comment: @user42582 There is no built-in option that adjusts that particular property within the function. `Tuples[]` is a worst case.

Comment: perhaps you could provide an contained example of the output you'd expect to get from an input list eg `{a,b,c}`.

Comment: Can you give a sample input/output pair please?

Comment: I am sure I am missing something but why not `DeleteDuplicates[Subsets[{a, c, b, c}]]` (giving {{}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {c, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, 
  c}, {b, c, c}, {a, b, c, c}})? As Szabolcs says, a sample input/output pair would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are after is

```
newSubsets[set_] := DeleteDuplicates[Subsets[set]];
```

It provides the result

```
newSubsets[{a, b, c, c}]
(* {{}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {c, c}, {a, b, 
  c}, {a, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {a, b, c, c}} *)
```

Comment: This works, but if the multiset has a lot of dupes, too much is disposed of.

Comment: And I see now, it was already posted in a hidden comment. Well, if push comes to shove, one could try to do it iteratively doing this for differently sized subsets one after another.

Comment: @J.M. It works!

Comment: @Richard, I don't doubt that it works, just that it is not combinatorially optimal when your multiset has many repeating elements.

Comment: @J.M. I tested it to display the subsets of a chess (m-)set which has 7 different pieces, 5 of them repeated. The `Length[]` of it came out exactly.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a version based on [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples) that should be much faster if there are a lot of repeated elements:

```
Multisubsets[list_] := With[{c = Tally[list]},
    Flatten /@ Tuples @ Replace[
        c,
        {k_, ct_} :> FoldList[Append, {}, Table[k, ct]],
        {1}
    ]
]
```

For your example:

```
res = Multisubsets[{a, b, c, c}]
```

> {{}, {c}, {c, c}, {b}, {b, c}, {b, c, c}, {a}, {a, c}, {a, c, c}, {a, b}, {a, 
>     b, c}, {a, b, c, c}}

Check:

```
Sort @ res == DeleteDuplicates @ Subsets[{a, b, c, c}]
```

> True

Timing test:

```
list = Join[Table[a, 20], Table[c, 3]];
r1 = DeleteDuplicates[Subsets[list]]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Multisubsets[list]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 == Sort[r2]
```

> {8.36211, Null}
>
> {0.000132, Null}
>
> True

Almost 4 orders of magnitude faster.